# CW structures on unitary sphere of a banach/Hilbert space

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Does the  unit sphere in a Banach  space carries a structure of  a CW complex? What about Finsler Manifolds?

Comment: The unit sphere in $c_0$ is the completion of a "uniform polyhedron", http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0346. The completion operation is quite harmless, for every uniform polyhedron $P$, in that there exists a self-homotopy $h_t$ of the completion of $P$ such that $h_0$ is the identity, and for each $t>0$, the image of $h_t$ lies in $P$. 

Answer (score 12):

The answer is no in infinite dimension (and yes in the finite dimensional case, of course). Because the sphere in a Banach space is Baire. But an infinite dimensional CW-complex is not, being a countable union of finite dimensional skeletons.